# In Shiny app, how to refresh data from MySQL db every 10 minutes if any change occured

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

I've made dashboard using shiny, shinydashboard and RMySQL package.
Following is what I wrote in order to refresh data every 10 minutes if any change occured.

In global.R

```
con = dbConnect(MySQL(), host, user, pass, db)
check_func <- function() {dbGetQuery(con, check_query}
get_func <- function() {dbGetQuery(con, get_query}
```

In server.R

```
function(input, output, session) {
    # check every 10 minutes for any change
    data <- reactivePoll(10*60*1000, session, checkFunc = check_func, valueFunc = get_func) 
    session$onSessionEnded(function() {dbDisconnect(con)})
```

However, above code infrequently generates corrupt connection handle error from check_func.

```
Warning: Error in .local: internal error in RS_DBI_getConnection: corrupt connection handle
```

Should I put dbConnect code inside server function? 
Any better ideas?

link: [using session$onsessionend to disconnect rshiny app from the mysql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175535/using-sessiononsessionend-to-disconnect-rshiny-app-from-the-mysql-server)

Answer (score 1):

"pool" package is the answer: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-basics.html

> This adds a new level of abstraction when connecting to a database: instead of directly fetching a connection from the database, you will create an object (called a pool) with a reference to that database. The pool holds a number of connections to the database. ... Each time you make a query, you are querying the pool, rather than the database. ... You never have to create or close connections directly: the pool knows when it should grow, shrink or keep steady.

I've got answer from here. -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/39661853/4672289